# How to filter by BlankNode id

Tags: filter, sparql, graphdb, blank-nodes

I'm trying to run this query in the SPARQL playground on **GraphDB**.

```
select * where { 
    ?s content:value ?value .
    FILTER REGEX(str(?value), "_:x1697BD364N0abcdd866d54")
}
```

`?value` are BNodes

I'm trying to filter all values where the BNode ID is: **_:x1697BD364N0abcdd866d54**

I've tried a few different ways to filter by the ID:

1. `FILTER REGEX(str(?value), "#bnode-id")`
2. `FILTER (?value), "#bnode-id")`

but none was a success.

#### Questions:

1. How would you filter based on a bnode id?
2. Is it possible to **STR(bnode)** ?

Comment: That can't work with blank nodes in SPARQL query even not with labeled blank nodes because blank nodes in graph patterns i) act as non-distinguished variables and ii) do **not** act as references to specific blank nodes in the RDF dataset.

Comment: The obvious solution would be to determine the blank node by some of its properties.

Comment: `FILTER REGEX` are heavy.

Comment: It's true. I'm still new to sparql :) so I guess my set of tools is a work in progress

Answer (score 4):

> 1. How would you filter based on a bnode <s>id</s> label?

[See](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/blank-nodes/info) the [blank-nodes](/questions/tagged/blank-nodes) tag info. In short, one can't rely on blank node labels in SPARQL queries:

> There need not be any relation between a label `_:a` in the result set and a blank node in the data graph with the same label.
>
> An application writer should not expect blank node labels in a query to refer to a particular blank node in the data.

If it is hard to distinguish blank nodes by their properties etc. in SPARQL, one can use GraphDB's internal resource identifiers.

```
PREFIX ent: <http://www.ontotext.com/owlim/entity#>
SELECT * {
    ?s content:value ?value .
    ?s ent:id ?id .
    FILTER (?id = 424242)
}
```

or

```
PREFIX ent: <http://www.ontotext.com/owlim/entity#>
SELECT * {
    ?s content:value ?value 
    BIND (ent:id(?s) AS ?id)
    FILTER (?id = 424242)
}
```

---

> 2. Is it possible to `STR(bnode)`?

No. From [17.4.2.5 str](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-str):

> ```
> simple literal  STR (literal ltrl)
> simple literal  STR (IRI rsrc)
> ```
>
> Returns the lexical form of `ltrl` (a literal); returns the codepoint representation of `rsrc` (an IRI).

Comment: That's nice
I was looking for a way to  filter  by bnode id, because I was looking for a specific id which I had. The GraphDB identifier is not a number which can help me here. but anyway, thats a nice trick :)

Comment: Do you have these blank node labels in your RDF file you want to import? These labels will change after importing.

Comment: @ueeiieu isn't it possible to identify the blank node by some of its properties?

Comment: @AKSW It is possible. My questions was mostly theoretical. I wanted to know why can I get the Blanknode ID